# Azure Search lucene regular expression with "<" and ">" symbols not working properly without escaping

Tags: c#, regex, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm having a hard time understanding why the "<" and ">" characters need escaping in my Lucene **full** query syntax that I'm using with Azure Search in .NET with the Azure SDK for .NET.

For example, this search expression: "/.*<Test.*/"

Gives me the following error:

> Error occurred when searching. Error message: Failed to parse regex
> expression. See https://aka.ms/azure-search-full-query-regex for
> supported expressions. Message: Failed to parse regex expression. See
> https://aka.ms/azure-search-full-query-regex for supported
> expressions.

If I escape the "<" character so that the search expression looks like this: "/.*\<Test.*/" then the query runs fine.

This seems weird to me because the "<" and ">" characters are not in the reserved characters for either [Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#escaping-special-characters) or for [Lucene regex](https://help.oncrawl.com/en/articles/1685982-lucene-regex-cheat-sheet#allowed-characters).

Am I missing something here?

Code for reference:

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Search.Documents;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Models;

const string endpoint = "{Endpoint}";
const string indexName = "{IndexName}";
const string queryApiKey = "{QueryApiKey}";
const string searchExpression = "/.<Test./";

var searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(endpoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey));

var options = new SearchOptions()
{
    QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full
};

searchClient.Search<SearchResult<SearchDocument>>(searchExpression, options);
```

JSON query for the Azure Search explorer:

```
{
  "search": "/.<Test./",
  "queryType": "full"
}
```

Comment: please share the code

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the Azure portal (with the search explorer of your search service). This might be a problem with something happening in between, e.g. sanitization, automatic escaping, URL encoding, ...

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride You need to use the queryType Full, that way I am able to reproduce this in the Search explorer.

{
  "search": "/.<Test./",
  "queryType": "full"
}

Comment: @Sampath I added code with which you can reproduce, I just think that this doesn't add much value to this question...

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. Consider creating an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

Comment: Created an issue for the documentation page: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/119648

Comment: `<` and `>` are unsafe characters. And you might need to escape them.